# What version of ffmpeg does libvlc use?

Tags: c++, linux, video, ffmpeg, libvlc

I am writing an application on linux (debian) that uses both libvlc and ffmpeg. 
Both run fine separately, but the moment I try to compile both functionalities into my app, libvlc stops working (complains about not finding the codecs).

I have been able to isolate the problem, basically libvlc runs fine until I compile the first line of ffmpeg code (av_register_all), at which point the linker brings in my own ffmpeg compiled lib,  and the moment I do that, it stops playing the file. Obviously I have 2 conflicting ffmpeg libs on my system, the one libvlc is using, and the newer one I built myself to write ffmpeg code.

My question is, how do I make libvlc work with the newer library? Considering there were functions deprecated in the newer ffmpeg code, would that involve recompiling libvlc? Is the libvlc code up to date with the newest ffmpeg library(new function signatures)?

Any help is appreciated!